# Langchain neo4j integration return no result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, openapi, langchain

I am using langchain and neo4j Libs to convert NL to cypher.
Everything is working, I even get the finish chain and it is clearly not empty

```
Full Context:
[{'d': {'name': 'Quinapril', 'ID': 'CHEMBL1592'}}]

> Finished chain.
```

But the final results is like this

```
I'm sorry, but I don't have the information.
```

Any Ideas what is happening? And how can i get full context results instead of the final interpretation.
I am following this blog steps [blog-link](https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/langchain-cypher-search-tips-tricks/)

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, openai_api_key=openai_api_key)

CYPHER_GENERATION_TEMPLATE = """Task:Generate Cypher statement to query a graph database.
Instructions:
Use only the provided relationship types and properties in the schema.
{schema}

The question is:
{question}"""


CYPHER_GENERATION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["schema", "question"], template=CYPHER_GENERATION_TEMPLATE
)

chain = GraphCypherQAChain.from_llm(
    llm,
    graph=graph,
    verbose=True,
    cypher_prompt=CYPHER_GENERATION_PROMPT
)

def convert_question_to_cypher(question):
    return (chain.run(question))

#convert_question_to_cypher("find name of drugs that target gene XYZ")
```

Comment: Ironically, your question doesn't have enough information either. Show your code, the full query and result, and describe your DB data model.

Comment: @cybersam Added the script, and it is "Neo4j DB QA chain" exactly the same as the provided link. For most of questions i got answers, But when directly ask a gene or drug name, while there is a context, the conversion part (i assume that's another hidden prompt or function) refuses to use the results. Wonder if there is a safety mechanism there.

Comment: Is there any `Generated Cypher`, and is it correct?

Comment: Yes, and it is legit! tested in neo4j itself and got the results back. Also the chain return the results. But the final decorator that convert is back to Natural language does not use the result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using qa_prompt??

```
chain = GraphCypherQAChain.from_llm(
    llm=llm,
    graph=graph,
    verbose=True,
    return_intermediate_steps=True,
    cypher_prompt=cypher_prompt,
    qa_prompt=qa_prompt
)
```

Something like this:

```
cypher_qa_prompt = """You are an assistant that helps to form nice and human understandable answers.
The information part contains the provided information that you must use to construct an answer.
The provided information is authoritative, you must never doubt it or try to use your internal knowledge to correct it.
Make the answer sound as a response to the question. Do not mention that you based the result on the given information.
If the provided information is empty, say that you don't know the answer.
Final answer should be easily readable and structured.
Information:
{context}

Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""

qa_prompt = PromptTemplate(
input_variables=["context", "question"], template=cypher_qa_prompt
```

)

Comment: Yess but no difference. At the end I am getting the mid results and generate the output on my own with a separate prompt.